# Universal property of the smash product (of pointed spaces)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, universal-property

Is there a universal property for the smash product (of pointed spaces or pointed CW-complexes or something of that ilk)?  I've seen the smash product of spectra defined with a universal property in terms of the smash product of pointed-spaces, but I was wondering if there was just some simple universal property you could put on these somewhat mysterious (to me) space-level operations.

EDIT: I was hoping for something more satisfying than the internal Hom adjoint.  The tensor product can be defined similarly, but I find the universal product in terms of bilinear maps more intuitive (although, when unraveled, they are the same thing).   I was hoping for something similar for smash.

Comment: The smash product is left adjoint to the internal hom. This is already explained on the Wikipedia article. 

Comment: I know, I just find that so unsatisfying because the internal Hom is more confusing than the Smash Product to me.  Thanks though.  

Comment: What's unsatisfying about the internal hom? 

Comment: Probably my own stubbornness.  

Comment: $X \wedge Y$ represents maps from $X \times Y$ that are base-point-preserving separately in each variable, just as the tensor product represents maps that are linear separately in each variable.

Comment: @Rune Why don't you post your comment as an answer? It is clear, on topic, and directly answers the question that was asked. 

Comment: @Rune and @Chris: Yea, that seems useful

Comment: I am unhappy that this question, which is a basic one and has at least the two relatively straightforward answers appearing in these comments, resulted in a brief conflict between members over the nature of an answer.  I am even less happy that the site's readers appear to be using their votes and comments to take sides and prolong the conflict (despite the principals moving to an off-site discussion).  The fact that this is not the only recent incident, even in the topology category, is depressing.  Please have consideration for those who you're writing about.

Comment: Akhil just taught me by email how to get a comment prompt. I apologize for my stupidity and will try not to err that way again.
I don't mind a few negative votes.  I have tried to give a mathematically convincing comment [answer] re smash products of spectra.  I agree with Tyler about consideration. While this is way off topic, I urge readers to look up the user list. You will see a 
remarkable paucity of women.  I've talked with many, and I have often gotten the response that they dislike the general tone. Way too much showing off, too little helpful teaching.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

$X \wedge Y$ represents maps from $X \times Y$ that are base-point-preserving separately in each variable, just as the tensor product represents maps that are linear separately in each variable.

Comment: I'm confused: $X \wedge Y$ represents or corepresents?

Comment: @ykm: "Corepresents", since we're discussing a property of maps *out of* $X \wedge Y$.

Answer (score 19):

There is a universal property of pointed spaces and the smash product, in an $\infty$-categorical sense. Let $S_*$ be the $\infty$-category of pointed spaces. Then the functor $S_\ast \times S_\ast \to S_\ast$ is the unique  colimit-preserving functor which satisfies $S^0 \wedge S^0 = S^0$. Since you mention spectra, this property is analogous to the characterization of the smash product of spectra as the unique functor which preserves colimits (in each variable) and such that $S^0 \wedge S^0 = S^0$ (for $S^0$ here the sphere spectrum).

One reason you should expect such a functor to a) exist and b) give an interesting symmetric monoidal structure is the following. The $\infty$-category $S_\ast$ is the free pointed  $\infty$-category on an object: that is, given a pointed $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ with all colimits, there is an equivalence $\mathrm{Fun}^L(S_\ast, \mathcal{C}) \simeq \mathcal{C}$ between colimit-preserving functors $S_* \to \mathcal{C}$ and objects of $\mathcal{C}$ (given by evaluation on $S^0$). This is a toy analog of the fact that $\mathrm{Fun}^L(Sp, \mathcal{C}) \simeq \mathcal{C}$ for a stable $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ with all colimits: that is, spectra are the free stable $\infty$-category on one object.

In general such "free" objects tend to admit symmetric monoidal structures. Here's one way to get the monoidal structure: by the above, pointed spaces are precisely 
the same thing as colimit-preserving functors $S_\ast \to S_\ast$ (i.e., any such is given by smashing with a pointed space). So the smash product of spaces comes from composing functors; in other words, the monoidal structure comes from composition on $\mathrm{Fun}^L(S_\ast, S_\ast)$. Another approach, which gives the symmetric monoidal structure, is to use Lurie's "tensor product" of presentable $\infty$-categories. I don't understand this very well, but I think the idea is that tensoring a presentable $\infty$-category with $S_*$ corresponds to taking the "pointed envelope," and so tensoring with $S_\ast$ is actually an idempotent operation on presentable $\infty$-categories.

This point of view is  useful with spectra; there the point is that spectra are the free stable presentable $\infty$-category on one object. There you have to replace "pointed" with "stable" throughout. 
Most of this is in Lurie's papers and his book "Higher Algebra." One upshot of this is that you can use it define the smash product of spectra, in a manner analogous to the tensor product of abelian groups.

Comment: That is perhaps the one downside of Peter's comment. I did not read it in its entirety, but I have always found everything worded and phrased in a kind welcoming manner. While I agree with a bit of the content of Peter's content, I would hope you not take offense in any way.

Comment: I'm thinking about pointed sets. The smash product is symmetric: why on earth should the composition of two cocontinuous functors $S_* \to S_*$ be commutative?

Comment: Just to be sure, these are colimits and not homotopy colimits? Does the same hold for homotopy colimits?

Comment: @fosco Given a symmetric monoidal category, the End of unit upgrades to a commutative algebra. Here we take the (very large) symmetric monoidal category of (potentially large) pointed categories with colimits, and small-colimit-preserving functors between them.

Comment: @Cayley-Hamilton They are "homotopy colimits" if you like, since the category in question is the category of pointed homotopy types (aka. anima).

Answer (score 12):

This is NOT an answer. I would like to answer Akhil's last question to me in a comment, but I just don't see any place to comment: no place to click in sight anywhere.  I'm not technologically adept. That
is the only reason I've given past "answers'' where comments would be appropriate.  The definition of "the'' smash product of spectra (admittedly off topic: I agree that Rune gave the best answer to the original space level question) is subtle. There is a beautiful model theoretic characterization in
Brooke Shipley's paper "Monoidal uniqueness of stable homotopy theory". Advances in Math. 160 (2001), 
217--240.  For the construction, done in terms of diagram categories (symmetric or orthogonal spectra), there is information packed into the domain category $\mathcal{D}$ that has to be accounted for and is more that can reasonably be described in terms of stable cells and gluing.  The first such constructions were two step, first a Kan extension to build a smash product of $\mathcal{D}$-spaces, which are in no sense spectra, and then a coequalizer "tensor product'' construction to (loosely) build in the spheres.  By enlarging $\mathcal{D}$ so as to pack more information into it, one can get a one-step construction,
as explained in Mandell, May, Schwede, and Shipley "Model categories of diagram spectra". Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 82(2001), 441--512.  Still, the universal property that is the characterization is not helpfully thought of in terms of gluing cells.  Rather, there is a simple naive construction of an external smash product that goes from $\mathcal{D}$-spectra to $(\mathcal{D}\times\mathcal{D})$-spectra, and then the role of Kan extension is to internalize it, using a choice of $\mathcal{D}$ that is itself symmetric monoidal.   The whole problem is to build the symmetric monoidal structure. That, on the space level, is already characterized by the function space adjunction.  On the spectrum level, defining function spectra is just as subtle as defining smash products.  Internalizing an obvious external smash product is also the theme in the $S$-module construction. This is intrinsic to the mathematics, at least on the level of actual categories.

Comment: +1. Although you say it's not an answer, I still think there's a lot of good, useful information being relayed here. 

Comment: Thank you for these additional remarks, and the two references. 

Answer (score 8):

Akhil, as one of those who struggled, I'd like to point out that nobody in a million years would have
first come up with such an esoteric construction (if it is one) of the smash product of spectra, and nobody who actually understands their calculational role would dream of thinking that to be the primary version
of the construction, or its most important property, or something that one would actually use as "the'' smash product.  It may arguably be a useful point of view, even a very useful one, but not for algebraic topology as a calculationally intensive subject.  It sheds no light on many of the calculationally central features of the smash product.  There are different categories of spectra with different good constructions of "the" smash product, and it doesn't help to give the idea that the notion is solely the $\infty$-category version.  It is not. And it really is too bad to try to tell people that "stability is an idea that you need $\infty$-categories to make sense of''.  That idea has been very well understood since before I started out 50 years ago.  You are referring narrowly to stability of $\infty$-categories, so you only ``need'' it when that is all that you are referring to.  Not everything in life (I mean mathematics, no, I mean algebraic topology) is $\infty$-categories, not by a long shot.  End of lecture.

Comment: 100% AGREED!!!! (excess "!" to meet the minimum character limit).

Comment: @Chris Gerig: Wait... Was that deemed offensive?

Comment: @Peter: While I agree that grumpiness is a reasonable reaction to some of the more enthusiastic and less restrained proponents of the $\infty$-category point of view, I don't think Akhil's answer falls in that camp.  Unless I missed something, he didn't claim to be describing the "primary version" or best version of the construction; he simply described _a_ version, without any claims that it was better than alternatives.  And he took the time to describe it non-tersely, so as to be useful to a wider audience.

Comment: For those who come here and see this as the top answer and are as confused as I was (Why is Peter May not answering the question? Why is he referring to Joseph Victor as 'Akhil'?), this is a comment to Akhil's answer below. Probably just didn't fit into a comment.

Comment: @Kevin: Akhil strayed pretty far off-topic to bring infinity categories into this thread.  There was no mention of them anywhere in the question.  

Comment: @Peter May, I appreciate the emphasis on calculation.  I do wish to actually calculate these things when one of the spaces involved is not a sphere.  

Comment: I think I may have written my answer somewhat over-zealously, and have edited it accordingly. My apologies, for the inaccuracies and any derailment. 

Comment: Akhil, no problem.  For others, Akhil and I have corresponded off this toy and are on the same wavelength.  Kevin, Akhil really didn't answer the question either.  A symmetric monoidal infinity category is not the same animal as a symmetric monoidal plain category.  A smash product in infinity category land does not answer a question about smash products as intended in the question.  Incidentally, for the same reason, I do not believe you can define "the" smash product
of spectra (as in Akhil's amendation) that way. What you get is only weakly analogous to tensor products.

Comment: @Omar: while I really appreciate the tone of your comment, I'd like to say that of course one *can* make a lengthy comment by filling up more than one comment box. And that's what Peter's "answer" is: a comment on a answer (to apply a neutral term for it). Not actually an answer itself. With all due respect to Peter May: answer boxes should only be used to answer the question. 


Comment: Or perhaps it would be more accurate to say that it's okay to comment on other answers in one's answer, but it should be in such a way as to shed light on the topic at hand. Again, with respect to Professor May, his reaction, however interesting it may be, was not directly pertinent to OP's question. I don't understand all the up-votes, except maybe as some kind of emotional or philosophical agreement with his general reaction. 

Comment: This answer amounts to a collection of acrimonious opinions, backed up by Peter May's weighty reputation rather than any kind of mathematical reasoning.  I don't find it helpful for understanding the smash product of pointed spaces.  Peter, if you would edit some math into your answer, I'm sure many people would appreciate it.

Comment: Akhil's answer describes a particular formalization of the idea that the smash product is characterized by: do what you expect on (stable) cells, and then glue up.  If no one in a millions years would have come up with that, we are all in trouble.

Comment: Apologies about answer vs comment. I don't spend much time on this and sometimes do not know how to comment (don't see a prompt). I write comments or answers when I want to try to teach something or when I see something that to my mind seriously misrepresents mathematics in a field I'm expert in. Many answers/comments seem seriously deficient to me. For example, it is not remotely a characterization of the symmetric monoidal smash product functor on spectra that "you do what you expect on (stable) cells and then glue up". That will not do and misrepresents the actual mathematics involved.

Comment: To continue, as I've said in an answer to another question, I know many fine mathematicians who have given up participation on math overflow.  I won't repeat the reasons.  The vast majority of participants are novices (look up users) and are not greatly helped by the most sophisticated answer to the simplest of questions. A full mathematical answer to the question at hand depends on the categorical location of the smash product.  Going from the category of (good) spaces (where the function space adjunction is a reasonable characterization) to the quasicategory of based spaces is a leap. 

Comment: Could you explain why the smash product is not characterized by "do what you expect on (stable) cells and then glue up"? My impression was that,  in explicit presentations such as symmetric or orthogonal spectra (not sure about $S$-modules here), such a statement characterized the smash product (as every spectrum is a colimit of spheres) and could be used to define it. 

Comment: (As in, the smash product was first defined on spheres, and then some sort of left Kan extension was used to extend it to all spectra.) 

Comment: @Peter: "A full mathematical answer to the question at hand depends on the categorical location of the smash product." Joseph Victor left it a little bit open what *precise* location he had in mind, but he apparently means a fairly vanilla category of spaces, and this would be a good opportunity for an expert like you to give a satisfying and full mathematical answer in the context of a suitably *convenient* category of spaces (if you want). If you think Akhil's answer was overly sophisticated for the purposes of the OP, then maybe you could offer a more suitable answer? 

Comment: One more thing (I don't want to get sidetracked here) -- the user list is maybe not the best gauge of who the regular MO participants are. A lot of people ask a single question, only to find out they were in the "wrong room", so to speak, but they wind up on the user list. I personally think the average level of understanding here among regular participants is about that of a good graduate class at a good university, say U. Chicago. I might even be underestimating the level. 


Comment: @Peter May: On several occassions I noticed your general remarks on MO, which I found interesting. In case you are not yet aware of it, I would thus like to mention that there is a seprate discussion-board for general matters of "MO-culture". To find it follow the link "meta"  (top of this page). Since this is sometimes a source of confusion I add that you cannot log in there with the actual MO account, but it is still direct to use: 'sign in' (top right) then 'apply for membership'; despite the wording, one can then, after choosing username and password, instantly use that board.   

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that.  I'll take a look if and when I have time.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, it was a misclick. Do you know if there is a universal property for the stable homotopy category (perhaps featuring homotopy colimits instead?) which is simpler and which could be found at around the time of the original Boardman paper? Such a property could help me to find which features of the non-derived homotopy category of spectra made it so that it took 30 some years to find, with S-modules and such. Thanks for your answer Prof. May.

Answer (score 2):

I have found in my work that it is often useful to generalise from pointed spaces to pairs of spaces. This is what led me to the  gluing theorem for homotopy equivalences published in my 1968 book "Elements of Modern topology", now "Topology and Groupoids".

Instead of pairs one can also do $M$-ads, where $M$ is an indexing set;  there is a product, and a smash product, and an exponential law using the latter, see section 4 of my 1964 paper ["Function spaces and product topologies"](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/functionspaces.pdf) Quart. J. Math. (1964).  As explained there: " However,  the  smashed product  as  defined  here of
spaces with base point $ X, Y$  is a 2-ad but is not a space with base point."

There should be some relation with the notion of Carrier, see Spanier and Whitehead, "Carriers and S-theory" so maybe there is a stable theory of carriers?

Also I do think the exponential law which is really about monoidal closed categories, not known, at least to me,  in 1964, should be seen as implying  a notion of bimorphism.