# 1-categorical universal properties for the smash product of pointed sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

**Question I.** Is the following statement, inspired by [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/105779), true?

> **Universal Property I.** The symmetric monoidal structure on the category $\mathsf{Sets}_*$ of pointed sets and pointed maps between them is uniquely determined by the following requirements:
>
> 1. *Two-Sided Preservation of Colimits.* The smash product functor
>    $$\wedge\colon\mathsf{Sets}_*\times\mathsf{Sets}_*\to\mathsf{Sets}_*$$
>    preserves colimits separately in each variable.
> 2. *The Unit Object Is $S^0$.* We have $\mathbb{1}_{\mathsf{Sets}_{*}}=S^0$.

If so, how can it be proved?

---

**Question II.** Is the following statement, inspired by [Gepner–Groth–Nikolaus's *Universality of multiplicative infinite loop space machines*](https://mathoverflow.net/a/105779), true?

> **Universal Property II.** The symmetric monoidal structure on the category $\mathsf{Sets}_*$ of pointed sets and pointed maps between them is the unique symmetric monoidal structure on $\mathsf{Sets}_*$ such that the free pointed set functor
> $$(-)^+\colon\mathsf{Sets}\to\mathsf{Sets}_*$$
> admits a symmetric monoidal structure.

Again, if this statement is true, how can we prove it?

---

**Note:** Everything here is taken $1$-categorically―there is no $\infty$-categorical stuff in sight.

Comment: **A note on asking two questions at once:** I'm asking two questions at once here since I expect there might be an easy reference or proof for them, and if someone knows the answer to one of the questions, then there's a good chance that they'll also know the answer for the other one. If this proves to be false, I'll split the question in two.

Comment: Since you mention explicitly that you don't want $\infty$-categories in the picture  it might help to make explicit what "unique" means. The answer to your question as I understand it is yes, in a suitable $(2,1)$-categorical sense, but I just want to make sure that you allow this

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Yep, a $(2,1)$-categorical (or $2$-categorical) universal property for those would be lovely!

Comment: I actually don't know how to give an enlightening proof that isn't the same as the $\infty$-categorical version (suitably contextualized), but presumably you would want to avoid that as well?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think that would be fine, too. The only thing I want to avoid is using tools from $\infty$-category theory, so a proof using only 1- and 2-category theory would actually be lovely, even if it follows the one from $\infty$-category theory rather closely.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I was thinking about UP I: is it equivalent to saying that the smash product of pointed sets and all the rest of the closed monoidal structure it comes with is the unique closed monoidal structure on $\mathsf{Sets}_*$ with unit $S^{0}$? I ask because I got the following proof idea for the later: the isomorphism
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sets}_*}(S^{0},[X,Y])\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sets}_*}(X,Y),$$
valid for any closed monoidal category, seems to force $[X,Y]$ to be the internal Hom of pointed sets since morphisms of pointed sets from $S^{0}$ to a pointed set $X$ are the [...]

Comment: same as elements of $X$, and then asking that this internal Hom have a left adjoint in each variable assembling into a closed monoidal category would determine $\wedge$ up to natural isomorphism. What do you think?

Comment: Emily: that would indeed determine the functor $\wedge$, but not necessarily the monoidal structure, which is more than just that functor (by the way, the reason I haven't written an answer to your question yet is that I'm thinking about II : I've been trying to figure out whether one needs to assume that the monoidal structure preserves colimits in each variable or whether it follows from $(-)_+$ being strong monoidal; it seems like it does but I haven't been able to prove it yet. For UP I, I could already write an answer following the lines I suggested earlier)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Ahhh that's too bad, having such a simple proof did sound too good to be true =/

Comment: I also feel like preservation of colimits ought to follow from $(-)_+$ being strong monoidal too by [applying this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributivity+of+limits+over+colimits#finite_products), but I can't seem how to conjure a proper proof either =/

Comment: As always, thank you so much, Maxime, I truly appreciate how helpful, kind, and patient you've always been to me regarding my questions here. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Of course, it's my pleasure :) I wrote an answer with what I know so far, hopefully someone else can chime in and figure out what I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't quite figure it out as I mentioned in the comments, let me already answer what I can - the answer to **Question I** is yes, and I'm enclined that it is so also for **Question II** but I'm missing an argument.

The point is that in **Question II**, one should be able to deduce that the monoidal structure preserves colimits in each variable: fix $X\in Set_*$, then it is of the form $(X_0)_+$ for some $X_0$, and for all $Y\in Set$, $X\otimes Y_+ \cong (X_0\times Y)_+ \cong X\wedge (Y_+)$. Since every $Y\in Set_*$ is of the form $(Y_0)_+$, this tells you that at least pointwise, $\otimes$ is given by the smash product. The same elementary argument shows that $X\otimes -$ preserves coproducts, but it seems a bit more subtle to properly show that it preserves pushouts although it should be doable (and I think elementary, once you spot it...)

Thus **Question II** *should* follow from **Question I**, and let me now focus on the latter.

The point that is made in the $\infty$-categorical proofs is that you can reinterpret "symmetric monoidal structure with 1." as "commutative algebra structure in $Pr^L_1$", the $(2,1)$-category of presentable $1$-categories equipped with the Lurie/Deligne/Kelley tensor product. From that perspective, together with the general theory of idempotent algebras, the claim follows from :

**Theorem** : $(Set_*,S^0)$ is an idempotent algebra in $Pr^L_1$, that is, the colimit-preserving functor $Set\to Set_*$ that picks out $S^0$ becomes an equivalence upon tensoring with $Set_*$.

*Proof*: The proof of that is exactly the same as that of HA 4.8.2.11, replacing each instance of "spaces" with "sets" and "$\infty$-category" with $1$-category. I can reproduce it with the relevant changes if you want, but for now let me just say that.

Here is a question to which I do not know the answer off the top of my head, and which might help with **Question II**: is the same result true if we replace $Pr^L_1$ with the category of categories admitting coproducts and coproduct-preserving functors ? Therein, $Set$ still turns out to be free on a point (it is surprising that $Set$ is both a free cocompletion and a free coproduct-completion), so it wouldn't be the most surprising thing but I'm not sure.

If not, then some extra argument is needed for **Question II**. Note that adding colimit-preservation of course makes it correct because then it satisfies the hypotheses of **Question I** :)

(and also note, as a side point, that because everything is presentable, *Two-sided colimit-preservation* is equivalent to monoidal closedness - and without presentability, it is implied by closedness)

Comment: Thank you so much, Maxime, and sorry for taking a bit to reply! It's taking a little longer than I expected for me to digest and explore a couple points in your answer. Would it be okay to get back to you in a bit, possibly with a couple questions, as I go making my way through these proofs and your answer?

Comment: Of course, no worries and no hurry :)

Comment: @MaximeRanzi Thank you so much again, Maxime :)